# Take data from log file in specified range of time in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am stuck with logic realization in linux, bash.
Actually I am new in shell scripting in linux.

The aim is to extract data from log file in specified range of time.
Logfile: test.log
It has huge data inside.
Logic is job runs on 05-FEB-2016 at 9:00 AM, it checks target LOG file and extracts all lines between 04-FEB-2016 15:00:00 PM and 05-FEB-2016 09:00:00 AM.

I used the command:

```
sed -n '/Feb 04/,/Feb 05/p' test.log
```

But it does not do what I need.
If someone came across with that problem, please share!

With regards!

Comment: Format of your logfile??

Comment: `Feb` and `FEB` are different strings.

Comment: Format of logfile - actually it is Oracle Alert file, not any special characters exist in the alert file.
extracted from that file:

`Thu Feb 04 22:00:00 2016
Setting Resource Manager plan SCHEDULER[0x32DC]:DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN via scheduler window
Setting Resource Manager plan DEFAULT_MAINTENANCE_PLAN via parameter
Thu Feb 04 22:00:00 2016
Starting background process VKRM
Thu Feb 04 22:00:00 2016
VKRM started with pid=29, OS id=27108 
Fri Feb 05 02:00:00 2016
Closing scheduler window
Closing Resource Manager plan via scheduler window
Clearing Resource Manager plan via parameter`